# best phrase choice for a derogatory reference to the "young generation"?

Tags: word-choice

which is the natural way to refer to the "young generation" (ex: now its the "millennial generation") in a derogatory way:
若**い**連中
若連中 // don't say the い
若者
若者達
若者ら

Maybe say something like:
今の日本の＿＿は前の経済的な習慣、例えば愛社精神とか集団意識とか年功序列など、を尊重するというより、給料しか考えずに適当に転職するわがままやつらなんじゃない。

Comment: What are you trying to say by `やつらんじゃない` ?

Comment: @Chocolate I think "やつ" is slang for "that guy". "ら" is a slang to make a noun plural. So, "やつら" is "those bunch of guys" (but slang)? I tried to say "A is B". "The young generation is a bunch of no goods, don't you think?." "んじゃない" The reasons "A is B" were young generation does not respect the tradition of "age-base promotion", "love of one's employer", "life-time employment", "sense of group togetherness among co-workers". Like going to lunch and senior employees pay for the meal. All those ideas helped rebuild Japan and influenced me to study Japanese. 今の若連中 don't know these customs?

Comment: @user312440 Did you possible mean **なん**じゃない？

Comment: @user, Then わがままやつら should be わがまま**な**やつら (literally "selfish guys") cos わがまま is a na-adjective. `今の若連中` <-- We don't say 「若連中」. It should be 若い連中.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, none of the five words/phrases you listed sound derogatory.  「若{わか}い連中{れんちゅう}」 might to a very small extent, but the rest sounds just normal.

The real question, to me at least, is: "Should you really use a derogatory term to refer to a group of millions of people?"  Not sure what the answer would be in your language and/or culture, but in Japanese culture, I can guarantee that that would be considered highly abnormal.  It is not like using a derogatory term to refer to a group of several that you personally know.

I would stick with 「若い連中」 myself.  If, however, you still want to know some derogatory terms for future reference, then we have:

- 「若造{わかぞう}」
- 「青二才{あおにさい}」
- 「（くそ）ガキ」
- 「ひよっこ」
- 「鼻{はな}たれ小僧{こぞう}」

Somebody stop me!

Comment: 「鼻たれ小僧」…もしかして「snot-nosed brat」の翻訳借用でしょうか？

Comment: Don't worry. It is only for a gag. For it to work, the word needs to be "unexpected from a gaijin with poor Japanese" so thank you for all those words. Every おじいさん, regardless of nationality, likes to rip on the younger generation.  Or maybe 年配者 is derogatory than おじいさん. anyway...definitely not 年増

Answer (score 0):

use 若者 is even formal and can hear from news. Add 連中 is  a derogatory way, like old people hating young lol.I've never heard 若連中 in Japan¯_(ツ)_/¯ so ''若い連中'' is suitable to that conversion.